# Do a manual abort in Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins

My original requirement is to check space and if enough space then proceed with the job or else abort the job. I am not failing the job as there has been another mail and process attached to failing of job. Thus I want something like:

```
if [ not enough space ]
then
    ... abort the job ....
fi
```

How can I abort the job through shell script or if any better option is there please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aborting a Jenkins job from within the executing shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117174/aborting-a-jenkins-job-from-within-the-executing-shell)

Comment: just put this as prebuild step

Comment: @mebada How do i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Put this script in the pre build step  (add shell build step before your job build step)

```
#max allowed usage .. maybe the whole disk
LIMIT = <put limit>
# you may replace the "." with your workspace dir
USED=`df . | awk '{print $5}' | sed -ne 2p | cut -d"%" -f1`

 if [ $USED -gt $LIMIT ]
 #If used space is bigger than LIMIT
 then
     exit 1
     #This would end the build and report failure
 fi
```

Comment: When i do exit 1 it fails the build
I want to abort the build because fail has some other action attached to it.